# Is this error in this paper of Langlands fixable?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras, conformal-field-theory, virasoro-algebra

The FQS criterion for the Virasoro algebra was discovered by Friedan, Qiu and Shenker ([1](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v52/i18/p1575_1)), but the mathematicians found their proof insufficient, so that, FQS ([2](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-107/issue-4/Details-of-the-nonunitarity-proof-for-highest-weight-representations-of/cmp/1104116227.full)) and Langlands ([3](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Infinite_Dimensional_Lie_Algebras_and_th.html?id=PI7gmgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)), published in the same time a complete proof.

There is an error in the paper of Langlands : ([3](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Infinite_Dimensional_Lie_Algebras_and_th.html?id=PI7gmgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)) lemma 7b page 148 (see also [here](https://sunsite.ubc.ca/DigitalMathArchive/Langlands/pdf/VirasoroAlg-ps.pdf) page 7) :

- $p=2$,  $q=1$,  $m=2$,  $h_{p,q}(m)= \frac{5}{8}$,  $M=4$
- $p=4$, $q=1$, $m=3$, $h_{p,q}(m)= \frac{7}{2}$,  $M=13$
- ...

yield case $(B)$, but $(p,q) \ne (1,1)$ and $m \ngtr q+p-1$.

**Remark** : In fact, we need to distinguish between $q \ne 1$ and $q=1$, not between
$(p,q)  \ne (1,1)$ and $(p,q)=(1,1)$).

This lemma is used in the rest of the paper.

> **Question**: Is there a way to fix the rest of the paper ?

**Remark** : This way was used by Sauvageot (([4](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-121/issue-4/Repr%C3%A9sentations-unitaires-des-super-alg%C3%A8bres-de-Ramond-et-de-Neveu/cmp/1104178251.full)) lemma 2 (ii) p 648), without fixing.

**References** :
([1](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v52/i18/p1575_1)) D. Friedan, Z. Qiu, S. Shenker, *Conformal invariance, unitarity, and critical exponents in two dimensions.*  Phys. Rev. Lett.  52  (1984),  no. 18, 1575--1578.

([2](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-107/issue-4/Details-of-the-nonunitarity-proof-for-highest-weight-representations-of/cmp/1104116227.full)) D. Friedan, Z. Qiu, S. Shenker, *Details of the nonunitarity proof for highest weight representations of the Virasoro algebra.* Comm. Math. Phys.  107  (1986),  no. 4, 535--542.

> ([3](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Infinite_Dimensional_Lie_Algebras_and_th.html?id=PI7gmgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)) R. P. Langlands, *On unitary representations of the Virasoro
> algebra.* Infinite-dimensional Lie algebras and their applications
> (Montreal, PQ, 1986),  141--159, World Sci. Publ., Teaneck, NJ, 1988.

([4](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-121/issue-4/Repr%C3%A9sentations-unitaires-des-super-alg%C3%A8bres-de-Ramond-et-de-Neveu/cmp/1104178251.full)) F. Sauvageot, *Représentations unitaires des super-algèbres de Ramond et de Neveu-Schwarz.*   Comm. Math. Phys.  121  (1989),  no. 4, 639--657.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This morning I just discovered [these corrigenda](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506191547/http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Eiohara/Corr/Corr-Chap11.pdf) of K. Iohara and Y. Koga (in which my name is cited in acknowledgement). In fact, three years ago, I have contacted K. Iohara (author, with Y. Koga, of the book *[Representation Theory of the Virasoro Algebra](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-85729-160-8/page/1)*) about this error (but I didn't know they fixed it).
I  do not yet read these corrigenda into details, but I guess it's ok (I hope).

**Another unfixed error for the Ramond algebra** :
As I said in remark, F. Sauvageot gave a proof 'à la Langlands' of the FQS criterion for the superVirasoro algebras ($N=1$): the Neveu-Schwarz algebra and the Ramond algebra.
Seven years ago, during my PhD, I have discovered this error in this paper of Langlands, reproduced in this paper of Sauvageot, so I decided to write a proof "à la FQS" of the FQS criterion for the Neveu-Schwarz and Ramond algebras.
In fact I discovered that this criterion runs for the Neveu-Schwarz case,
but **not for the Ramond case** :
We can prove lemma 4.19 p 22 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0077) (Neveu-Schwarz case)
thanks to the curves $h=h^{m}_{pp}$, but the Ramond case doesn't have these curves !
So it's ok for the Neveu-Schwarz case (and I guess Sauvageot's paper is fixable in this case by using the corrigenda above), but for the Ramond case,
the FQS criterion gives the discrete series plus some representations of
charge $c_{m}$ with $m$ non-interger !

**Sketch of fixing** :
For excluding these last representations we can use an argument of
fusion:
$$ (R) \boxtimes (R) \to (NS) $$

It's known that the fusion of two representations of the Ramond algebra (R), in the discrete series at central charge $c_{m}$, give a (discrete series) representation of the Neveu-Schwarz algebra (NS) at the same central charge $c_{m}$ (the Ramond algebra is given by a twisted vertex module over the vertex operator algebra of the Neveu-Schwarz algebra). But we know
that the Neveu-Schwarz case doesn't contain such representations at central
charge $c_{m}$ with $m$ non-interger, the result follows.